# Which is fast: store 10^5 size array in android app and search in it or fire queries of search and get data from database

Tags: java, android, arrays, database, time-complexity

I am currently working on an app that have 15000+ rows and 20+ columns array on database. If a user search in app then two things I can do
1. Is I will save all data from database when app runs and then after search for the user preference data. 
2/ I will convert user data into a query and fire on database and retrieve data from database at same time.
Additionally I want to ask if I store 10^6*20 size array in app then how much space it take and how it behave to reload the app.
And if I fetch then what will be fetching time complexity in worst case data usage.
Thanks for your appreciation in before.

Comment: if i am not totally mistaken, the array would have a size of ~160mb (10^6*20 * 8byte). this wouldn't be very practicable to have in memory all the time. databases will be much faster, even more, if they run on the device

Comment: How much data you are going to present in one page? In the similar situation I i had to fetch only row ids to make a list and then fetched row-by-row data as needed (only for visible parts) directly from a view adapter. Of course LRU cache in a middle helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks, @XtremeBaumer. Find it helpful and I also practiced in both and database query is fast.

Answer (score 1):

With only about 200 MB or less of data either way will be fast, assuming you allocate enough heap to the process. In the modern era that is not much data. Which will be faster? That all depends.

How fast is your I/O system? What database would you use? How would you code your algorithm? Are you doing any processing in parallel? What bugs have you written into your code? What amount of overall program time does access to these data use? What else is running on the system?

Only *actual measurement* of both approaches under very well controlled conditions that simulate realistic loads will reveal which is faster.

But at what cost? More complex systems have more risk and costs. Complicated premature "optimization" code makes code brittle and hard to understand. Workarounds​ take time and effort, wasted time and effort if there's nothing to work around.

So instead of asking which is fast(er), ask what makes sense. What gets the job done at all? What costs the least to do? What's more correct? What minimizes risk?

Comment: On Android most devices will not allow an app to have a 200MB heap. Also it is device dependent you choose how much memory to allocate to a process on Android.

Comment: That is definitely a factor in deciding what makes sense. Note that this consideration is not related to speed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get your point and find helpful. +1